# How can I check a user's bounties history?

Tags: support, bounties

Is there a way to see the bounties a user has placed up to now, on what questions and whom the bounties have been awarded to? I've been trying to look for this information on the sites help centers, but I couldn't find the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Profile → Activity → bounties → offered.

This is [yours](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/66974/josh?tab=bounties&sort=offered) on ELU:

> [image]

There is no way to see in the list who got the bounty though,  you'll have to go question by question to see that, or use SEDE.

Comment: Ok, very easy actually, thanks. Should I delete this question?

Comment: No, others might find it helpful too at some point. :)